# Unable to apply xpathApply to an object of class "list" in R

Tags: r, xml, list, xpath, sapply

I am trying to query PubMed with a list of PMIDs and trying to get some information out for each article such as the publication type. I would like to ultimately create a data frame consisting of 2 columns: one listing the PMIDs and the other listing the publication type. Some publications have more than one publication type so a PMID should be replicated for each publication type. For example:

```
    PMID           Publication.type
    26946365       Journal.article
    26946365       Meta.analysis
    26946365       Twin.study
    28399511       Journal.article
```

I am able to create this if I break up my list of PMIDs into batches and do it separately (i.e., batch1<-pubmed[1,500,], etc). But I would like to do it more succinctly. My code is:

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(stringr)
    library(regexr)
    library(rentrez)
    library(XML)

    pubmed<-df(PMID codes)

    into.batches<-function(x,n) split(x,cut(seq_along(x),n,labels=FALSE))
    batches<-into.batches(pubmed.fwd$PMID, 14)        
    headings<-lapply(1:14, function(x) {paste0("Batch",x)})
    names(batches)<-headings

    fwd<-sapply(batches, function(x) entrez_fetch(db="pubmed", id=x, rettype="xml", parsed=TRUE))
```

This all works fine. My problem is when I use the xpathSApply function to get the xmlValue, such as the publication type or the PMID from the XML:

```
    pub.type<-xpathSApply(fwd, "//PublicationTypeList/PublicationType", xmlValue)
    or.pmid<-xpathSApply(fwd, "//ArticleId[@IdType='pubmed']", xmlValue)
```

I get the following error:

```
    Error in UseMethod("xpathApply") : 
    no applicable method for 'xpathApply' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Am I just not able to do this because fwd is a list with 14 different vectors? I tried using regular sapply but I get the same error message. I was really hoping I don't have to do 14 different batches for each of the functions and it seems like there should be a way to do it but I am getting stuck here. Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply loop through your nested list with `lapply` to retrieve the corresponding, parsed XML data. Below will return a list of equal length to `fwd`, each item containing a list of two named elements for *pub.type* and *or.pmid*:

```
pubmedList <- (fwd, function(f)
    list(pub.type = xpathSApply(f, "//PublicationTypeList/PublicationType", xmlValue),
         or.pmid = xpathSApply(f, "//ArticleId[@IdType='pubmed']", xmlValue)))
```

Alternatively, create two lists:

```
pub.type_List <- (fwd, function(f)
        xpathSApply(f, "//PublicationTypeList/PublicationType", xmlValue))

or.pmid_List <- (fwd, function(f)
        xpathSApply(f, "//ArticleId[@IdType='pubmed']", xmlValue))
```